# Importing particle simulation from Houdini to Blender

Tags: particles, import, alembic

I have a particle simulation in Houdini that I'd like to import into blender. The particle simulation has instanced objects on every particle in Houdini, so I've tried just exporting it from there as an alembic, but when importing, Blender treats every particle as a separate object (which is in no way ideal for what I'm doing). Ideally I'd like to just have all the geometry from the alembic imported as a single object in Blender. Can it be done this way in blender?
William

Comment: You could use dupliverts and mesh sequence cache modifier to bring a Houdini system into blender. It wouldn't really be a *single* object, although instances in blender are usually fairly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use an *Add* node at the end of your Houdini grain or particle sim and then in the third tab check Add Particle System*,.

When you render it out as an alembic Blender should read it as an object.